# C/C++ High efficiency sock reverse proxy

Tags: c++, c, sockets, proxy

i have to write an high efficiency sock reverse proxy in C/C++, so i was wondering, is there any library/framework to easily handle sockets, proxying, etc just to focus on the main part of the project (not the proxy itself :)) ?

Something like the ACE framework but possibly i little bit smaller and/or proxy oriented ...

Thanks

Comment: Is it going to be an http proxy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`libevent`](http://monkey.org/~provos/libevent/) is pretty good. ACE is horrible :)

Comment: a little example on how to use libevent to implement a proxy? :) cool anyway :)

Comment: I wrote a reverse proxy for libevhtp (an alternative http server for libevent) not long ago: https://gist.github.com/3911541

Answer (score 0):

[Delegate](http://www.delegate.org/delegate/) is a good existing generic proxy tool.  You should be able to fairly easily extend it for the protocol of interest.